# Object loses reference

Tags: objective-c, variables, reference, nsobject, ikimagebrowserview

I have a IKImageBrowserView which has its own controller - BrowserController.h + .m

```
@interface BrowserController : NSWindowController{
    NSMutableArray *_images;
}
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet IKImageBrowserView *imageBrowser;

-(void)addMultipleImages;
```

When I run the app for the first time, the staring image loads, but when I click a button to add other images and call a method from another class I don't get any results. I have noticed that my _imageBrowser loses the reference and becomes nil.

How could I solve this issue?

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BrowserController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate{
    BrowserController *imageBrowserController;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    imageBrowserController = [BrowserController sharedManager];

}

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {
    [imageBrowserController addMultipleImages];
}


@end
```

BrowserController.m

```
#import "BrowserController.h"
@interface myImageObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *_path;
}
@end


@implementation myImageObject

/* our datasource object is just a filepath representation */
- (void)setPath:(NSString *)path
{
    if(_path != path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }
}

/* required methods of the IKImageBrowserItem protocol */
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark item data source protocol

/* let the image browser knows we use a path representation */
- (NSString *)imageRepresentationType
{
    return IKImageBrowserPathRepresentationType;
}

/* give our representation to the image browser */
- (id)imageRepresentation
{
    return _path;
}

/* use the absolute filepath as identifier */
- (NSString *)imageUID
{
    return _path;
}

@end


@interface BrowserController ()

@end

@implementation BrowserController

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{

    myImageObject *p;
    p = [[myImageObject alloc]init];
    [p setPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Unknown" ofType:@"jpg"]];
    _images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [_images addObject:p];

    [self updateDataSource];
}


- (void)updateDataSource{

    [_imageBrowser reloadData];
}

-(NSUInteger) numberOfItemsInImageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *)aBrowser{
    return [_images count];
};

-(id)imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *)aBrowser itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    return [_images objectAtIndex:index];
};

- (void)updateDatasource
{
    [_imageBrowser reloadData];
}

- (void)addMultipleImages{
    myImageObject *p;
    p = [[myImageObject alloc]init];
    [p setPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Unknown" ofType:@"jpg"]];
    _images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [_images addObject:p];
    [_images addObject:p];
    [_images addObject:p];

    [_imageBrowser reloadData];
}


+ (id)sharedManager {
    static BrowserController *sharedMyManager = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}


@end
```

Comment: You can put a breakpoint on the @property itself, and see what sets it to nil.

Comment: Just tried this. Stops on breakpoint only on initialisation, when the app is loaded first time.

Comment: are you actually alloc-ing and init-ing it?

Comment: updated the question with the source code

Comment: Do you have more than one `BrowserController`?  I see that you have a `sharedManager` that suggests a singleton but that you also have an `awakeFromNib` implementation that suggests an instance might be part of interface loading.  Try logging the address of your `BrowserController` at strategic points to see if it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>There is some confusion as to the name of the class where you mention it's called `ImageBrowserController` at the start of your question and it looks like it's called `BrowserController` at the end of your question.</sub>

The issue is that you allocate `_images` in `awakeFromNib` which is never called given the class is created via the singleton pattern (`sharedInstance`) and not loaded from a `.nib` file.

Therefore move the code from `awakeFromNib` into `init` and dump `awakeFromNib`:

BrowserController.m:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myImageObject *p = [[myImageObject alloc]init];
        [p setPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Unknown" ofType:@"jpg"]];
        _images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [_images addObject:p];

        [self updateDataSource];
   }
    return self;
}
```

Further confusion: you have implemented an `initWithFrame` method.  Why?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion with BrowserController and ImageBrowserController. They do the same thing, just been playing around trying to find the problem.
So now I have moved everything from AwakeFromNib to init, but now not even the test image gets loaded. Well anyways, here's the full code here: http://we.tl/6p74AqwaIr